# HTML Email - Media queries causes different height on images

Tags: html, css, email, media-queries, html-email

I have a problem, because I want to make a block in an email with one big image to the left, and 4 small images to the right.
[Example of the block I want to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaKyC.png)

On mobile I just want it to downscale it.
So I've set it up, but the problem is, when viewed on mobile devices the small images does not get the same height, because the total width is 350px and 1/4 of that is 87,5px. Therefore the first column gets 88px and the second column gets 87px and they therefore also upscale in height, causing them to not have the same height.
[See example of not the same height on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvbQd.png)

Is there a way to keep them all at the same height on mobile, even though they aren't exactly the same width when calculated in percentages? - And in a way that it also works, with images of other proportions of course.

This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<meta content="width=device-width" name="viewport" />
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<![endif]-->
 <!--[if gte mso 15]>
  <style>
    /* Outlook 2013 Height Fix */
    body table { font-size: 0; line-height: 0; }
    table tr { font-size:1px; mso-line-height-alt:0; mso-margin-top-alt:1px; mso-height-source:0;}
    table td { font-size: 0px; line-height: 0;mso-width-source:1px;}
  </style>
<![endif]-->
<title>-</title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    width: auto !important;
    background: #f7f7f7;
}
.ReadMsgBody {
    width: 100%;
}
#outlook a {
    padding:0;
}
.ReadMsgBody {
    width:100%;
}
.ExternalClass {
    width:100%;
}
.ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {
    line-height: 100%;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 0;
    mso-table-lspace:0pt;
    mso-table-rspace:0pt;
}
table td {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border: 0;
    mso-table-lspace:0pt;
    mso-table-rspace:0pt;
}
p {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    margin-bottom:0;
}

a { text-decoration: none !important;    }

a:visited { color: inherit !important;  }
 span.MsoHyperlink {
      mso-style-priority:99;
      color:inherit;
  }
  span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed {
      mso-style-priority:99;
      color:inherit;
  }
.a_price a {
    color: #000001;
    text-decoration: none;
}
img {
    border:0;
    height:auto;
    line-height:100%;
    outline:none;
    text-decoration:none;
    -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;
}
.online a {
    color:#8a8a8b;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.buttonWhite a, .buttonWhite2 a {
    color: #000001;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.buttonBlack a, .buttonBlack2 a {
    color: #fffffe;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.footer a {
    color:#505359;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.copyright a {
    color:#767676;
    text-decoration:underline;
}

*[class="header"] img, *[class="columnTop"] img {
    height: auto !important;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
table.header2 td.header3 {
    height: auto !important;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 600px ){
*, *::before, *::after {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
width: auto !important;
}
*[class="fullWidth"] {
width: 100% !important;
max-width: 100% !important;
min-width: 100% !important;
}
*[class="tableWrapper"] {
width: 350px !important;
max-width: 350px !important;
min-width: 350px !important;
}
*[class="table600"] {
width: 90% !important;
margin: 0 auto;
}
*[class="online"] {
 text-align: center !important;
 padding: 10px !important;
}
*[class="logo"] {
 padding: 20px 0 30px 0 !important;
}
*[class="mobilelogo"] {
 width:145px !important;
}
*[class="icon1"] {
 width: 34px !important;
}
    *[class="icon2"] {
 width: 44px !important;
}
    *[class="icon3"] {
 width: 42px !important;
}
*[class="header"] img, *[class="columnTop"] img, *[class="columnBottom2"] img {
min-width: 100% !important;
width: 100% !important;
height: auto !important;
}
*[class="header2"] img {
min-width: 100% !important;
width: 100% !important;
height: auto !important;
}
table.header2 td .header3 {
min-width: 100% !important;
width: 100% !important;
height: auto !important;
}
*[class="floatTable"], *[class="floatTableMiddle"] {
float: none !important;
width: 100% !important;
}
*[class="floatTableMiddle"] {
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
*[class="column"] {
 min-width: 50% !important;
 width: 50% !important;
 max-width: 50% !important;
}
*[class="columnSmall"] {
 min-width: 33% !important;
 width: 33% !important;
 max-width: 33% !important;
}
*[class="column25"] {
 min-width: 25% !important;
 width: 25% !important;
 max-width: 25% !important;
}
*[class="columnFooter"] {
 width: 32.66666666666667% !important;
 height: auto !important;
 padding: 18px 0 20px 0 !important;
}
*[class="columnFooterSpacer"] {
 width: 1% !important;
}
*[class="columnFooter"] img {
 max-width: 70px !important;
 width: 100% !important;
 height: auto !important;
}
*[class="columnTop"], *[class="columnTop2"] {
width: 100% !important;
display:table-header-group !important;
}
*[class="columnBottom"], *[class="columnBottom2"] {
width: 100% !important;
display:table-footer-group !important;
}
*[class="buttonArrow"] {
 padding-right: 15px !important;

}
*[class="buttonWhite2"], *[class="buttonBlack2"] {
 padding-left: 15px !important;
}
*[class="content"] {
font-size: 14px !important;
line-height: 24px !important;
}
*[class="mobileHeight"] {
 height: 30px !important;
 width: 350px !important;
max-width: 350px !important;
min-width: 350px !important;
}
*[class="mobileHide"] {
display: none;
}
*[class="tableButton"] {
width:100% !important;
min-width: 100% !important;
}
*[class="navigation"] {
padding-bottom: 20px !important;
}
*[class="navigation"] td {
padding: 0 !important;
text-align: center !important;
width: auto !important;
}
*[class="navigation"] td img {
margin: 0 auto !important;
height: 12px !important;
width: auto !important;
}
*[class="buttonWhite"], *[class="buttonBlack"] {
padding-top: 5px !important;
padding-bottom: 5px !important;
}
    
.abanimg {
width:105px !important;
height:auto !important;
} 

table[class="r_tableWrapper"] {
width: 350px !important;
max-width: 350px !important;
min-width: 350px !important;
margin: 0 auto !important;
}
td[class="r_tableWrapper"] {
width: 100% !important;
max-width: 100% !important;
min-width: 100% !important;
}
*[class="r_columnWrapper"] {
width: auto !important;
max-width: 300px !important;
margin: 0 auto !important;
margin-bottom: 20px !important;
}
*[class="r_columnTop"] {
width: 100% !important;
display:table-header-group !important;
}
*[class="r_columnBottom"] {
width: 100% !important;
display:table-footer-group !important;
}
*[class="r_buttonWhite"], *[class="r_buttonBlack"] {
font-size: 14px !important;
padding-left: 15px !important;
}

table[class="a_tableWrapper"] {
width: 350px !important;
max-width: 350px !important;
min-width: 350px !important;
margin: 0 auto !important;
}
td[class="a_tableWrapper"] {
width: 100% !important;
max-width: 100% !important;
min-width: 100% !important;
}
*[class="a_contentWrapper"] {
padding-left: 25px !important;
padding-right: 25px !important;
width: 100% !important;
max-width: 100% !important;
min-width: 100% !important;
}
*[class="a_header"] img {
min-width: 100% !important;
width: 100% !important;
height: auto !important;
}
*[class="a_column"] {
float: left !important;
width: 100% !important;
display: block !important;
}
*[class="a_column"] table {
width: 80% !important;
margin: 0 auto !important;
}
*[class="a_column"] table img {
width: 250px !important;
height: auto !important;
}
*[class="a_price"] {
font-size: 15px !important;
}
*[class="a_module"] {
font-size: 20px !important;
}
*[class="a_table600"] {
width: 90% !important;
margin: 0 auto;
}
*[class="a_floatTable"] {
float: none !important;
width: 100% !important;
}
*[class="a_floatTable"]:first-of-type {
margin-bottom: 15px;
}
*[class="a_button"] {
padding-left: 10px !important;
padding-right: 10px !important;
padding-bottom: 10px !important;
}
*[class="a_button"] table {
float: none !important;
margin: 0 auto !important;
width: 100% !important;
}
*[class="a_title"] {
font-size: 25px !important;
}    
    
}
    
       
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
*[class="tableWrapper"], *[class="mobileHeight"] {
width: 320px !important;
max-width: 320px !important;
min-width: 320px !important;
}
    table[class="a_tableWrapper"] {
width: 320px !important;
max-width: 320px !important;
min-width: 320px !important;
margin: 0 auto !important;
}
    
    table[class="r_tableWrapper"] {
width: 320px !important;
max-width: 320px !important;
min-width: 320px !important;
}
   
</style>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#f7f7f7" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0" bgcolor="#f7f7f7">
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="fullWidth">
        <tr>
          <td align="center">
      
<table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="tableWrapper" bgcolor="#fcfcfc" align="center">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td class="tableWrapper" style="width: 600px; max-width: 600px; min-width: 600px;" align="center">
   <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td class="column" width="300" align="left" valign="top">
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
       <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td class="header"><img src="http://image.s7.exacttarget.com/lib/fe9d13727764027c75/m/1/image-300_Placeholder.jpg" width="300" height="456" alt="" border="0" style="display: block;" /></td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
      </td>
      <td class="column" width="300" align="left" valign="top">
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
       <tbody>
        <tr>   
         <td class="column" width="150" align="left" valign="top">
         <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
          <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td class="header"><img src="http://image.s7.exacttarget.com/lib/fe9d13727764027c75/m/1/image-300_Placeholder.jpg" width="150" height="228" alt="" border="0" style="display: block;" />
            <img src="http://image.s7.exacttarget.com/lib/fe9d13727764027c75/m/1/image-300_Placeholder.jpg" width="150" height="228" alt="" border="0" style="display: block;" /></td>
           </tr>
          </tbody>
         </table>
         </td>
         <td class="column" width="150" align="left" valign="top">
         <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
          <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td class="header"><img src="http://image.s7.exacttarget.com/lib/fe9d13727764027c75/m/1/image-300_Placeholder.jpg" width="150" height="228" alt="" border="0" style="display: block;" />
            <img src="http://image.s7.exacttarget.com/lib/fe9d13727764027c75/m/1/image-300_Placeholder.jpg" width="150" height="228" alt="" border="0" style="display: block;" /></td>
           </tr>
          </tbody>
         </table>
         </td> 
        </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>


       
       </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You made the background color and the entire color in the images the same color. https://ol2013.capture.litmuscdn.com/856a0d6d-f092-47ff-a982-4eca38fff3e4/results/ol2013-vertical-allowed-1366.png I ran this through Litmus to see if I could determine the problem, but I can't tell what is an image, what is the background. This makes it really hard to determine what is the issue. The harder you make it for people to help you, the less desire we have to help.

Comment: The given answer didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are after. I have used you images but the table had to be redone. You had used quiet a lot of tables, maybe your editor is doing it (shurgs).

Breakdown of what I did:
Each image style has width 100% and height auto. This will mean the image resizes with the columns (each columns are 50% of the table).

Since you had provided these images I have used the same color as the background ;-)

Check out the code to see how it works.

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="max-width: 600px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="50%" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#5e5e5e"><img src="http://image.s7.exacttarget.com/lib/fe9d13727764027c75/m/1/image-300_Placeholder.jpg" alt="" border="0" style="display: block; width:100%; height:auto;" /></td>
      <td width="50%">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td width="50%" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#5e5e5e"><span class="header"><img src="http://image.s7.exacttarget.com/lib/fe9d13727764027c75/m/1/image-300_Placeholder.jpg" alt="" border="0" style="display: block; width:100%; height:auto;" /></span></td>
     <td width="50%" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#5e5e5e"><span class="header"><img src="http://image.s7.exacttarget.com/lib/fe9d13727764027c75/m/1/image-300_Placeholder.jpg" alt="" border="0" style="display: block; width:100%; height:auto;" /></span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td width="50%" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#5e5e5e"><span class="header"><img src="http://image.s7.exacttarget.com/lib/fe9d13727764027c75/m/1/image-300_Placeholder.jpg" alt="" border="0" style="display: block; width:100%; height:auto;" /></span></td>
     <td width="50%" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#5e5e5e"><span class="header"><img src="http://image.s7.exacttarget.com/lib/fe9d13727764027c75/m/1/image-300_Placeholder.jpg" alt="" border="0" style="display: block; width:100%; height:auto;" /></span></td>
   </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Run the code above and do a full screen, resize the browser to see it work.

Cheers